# Facing issue while Archiving build to Appstore

Tags: ios, build, app-store

App is successfully archieving. But when I upload the app to **appstore**, I'm facing this kinda issue.

> ERROR ITMS-90017: "This bundle is invalid. The IPA format requires a
>   top-level directory named Payload, containing only a .app bundle and
>   optional plugins in a Plugins directory."

I have checked **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44262946/error-itms-90017-this-bundle-is-invalid-the-ipa-format-requires-a-top-level-di) and other SO post**. But I didn't get any solution and no idea where would be the problem comes from.

**Tried solution:**

1. verified bundle id and certification.
2. recreate provisioning and certificate file.
3. In Info.plist, added

   - CFBundleInfoDictionary version 6.0
   - "LSRequiresIPhoneOS" as a BOOL with the value YES to your target.

**updated:**

4. In Xcode Organizer select "Export..." -> "Save for development..." The result xxx.ipa file rename to xxx.zip and then unzip it. It has a **"Payload"** directory.

Still facing the problem. Please help me out on this.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to unzip 'ipa' file. It should contain "Payload" directory. If it doesn't then there is a problem with project settings. Maybe after you did unzip the problem will be clear

Comment: @lgor kotkovets thank you for your reply but it didn't work.

Comment: but what is inside ipa file?

Comment: @Igor Kotkovets could you plz tell me or elloborate where would i get the ipa file and how to go to payload directory?

Comment: In Xcode Organizer select "Export..." -> "Save for development..." The result xxx.ipa file rename to xxx.zip and then unzip it. There is have to be "Payload" directory

Comment: Let me try and check that. Thanx

Comment: Yes. It has payload directory and contains .app . why still facing the same issue?